# Linear ordering with predecessor and successor

Tags: order-theory

Let $(P,\leq)$ be a totally ordered set such that

1. for all $p\in P$ the set $\{q\in P: q > p\}$ has a smallest element (that is, $p$ has a successor), and
2. for all $p\in P$ the set $\{q\in P: q < p\}$ has a largest element (that is, $p$ has a predecessor).

It seems fairly intuitive to me that this forces that $P\cong\mathbb{Z}$ - but how does one prove this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about $\mathbb{Z}^2$ with the lexicographic order?

$$(a,b) < (a', b') \text{ if } \begin{cases} a< a' \text{ or} \\ a=a', b<b'\end{cases}$$

The predecessor of $(a,b)$ is $(a, b-1)$ and the successor of $(a,b)$ is $(a, b+1)$.

In the usual order on $\mathbb{Z}$, every interval $[p,q]$ is finite. But the interval $[(0,0), (1,1)]$ is infinite.

Comment: Nice example! I also thought OP's statement was true.

Comment: Take *any* linear ordering $A$ and look at the lexicographic product $A\times\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I agree.